# Set value in textbox in external website when user clicks link on my website

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have my own website. There is a link on my website which redirect me to the externel website. I want to know how to set value in textbox in that externel website when user click link on my website

Comment: You want to set a value in a textbox on someone else his website?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to save opened window handler?

```
var openedWindow = window.open(....
```

Instead of using direct links.
Or maybe pass parameters through url?

Comment: there is website called "http://www.igiworldwide.com/search_report.aspx".This website returns the stone reports when entered "report no" and "carat" in textbox. In my website there is link, which on click open the mentioned website.I dont want that user reenter the textbox value , instead i want that it will automaticaly

Comment: You should check the API of that resourse, It's probably already resolved.

Answer (score 0):

you can add parameters on the URL.

just modify the link accordingly, and read the URL parameter on the other site.

(this assumes you don't care the possibility that someone fills the parameters with fake info)

Comment: there is website called "http://www.igiworldwide.com/search_report.aspx".This website returns the stone reports when entered "report no" and "carat" in textbox. In my website there is link, which on click open the mentioned website.I dont want that user reenter the textbox value , instead i want that it will automaticaly

Answer (score 0):

Unless that site has implemented something to let you set that (e.g. if they populate the text field using data from the query string), you can't.

There is no standard mechanism for pre-populating forms via a link to the page containing the form.

Comment: there is website called "http://www.igiworldwide.com/search_report.aspx".This website returns the stone reports when entered "report no" and "carat" in textbox. In my website there is link, which on click open the mentioned website.I dont want that user reenter the textbox value , instead i want that it will automaticaly

Comment: Repeating the question won't change the answer.